# Calculus - Check if the line is parallel to the plane

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Check if $r = (3,0,2) + t(1,-2,2)$ is parallel to the plane $4x + y - z = 10$ Does it lie in the plane?

I'm new to vectors and I'm just wondering how would I solve a question like this!

Comment: What would a normal vector to the plane be (that is, an expression for it)?  Is the direction of the vector $ \ \vec{r} \ $ perpendicular to it?  How can you test that?

Answer (score 1):

When the equation of a plane is given as $ax + by + cz = d$ we know that the vector $(a,b,c)$ is orthogonal to the plane. Therefore, we know that the dot product $(a,b,c) \cdot (1, -2, 2) = 0$ if and only if $r(t)$ is parallel to the plane.

If you have that a plane is parallel to a line, in order to see if it lies in the plane, you must only check one point. Indeed, if $t = o$ we have that $r(0) = (3,0,2)$ is a point in the plane since $4(3) + 0 -2 = 10$. Piece this together for your final answer.